# Cant select my 2BE HDD in Ubuntu installation

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I am trying to download Linux to my laptop for work. I have 2 times 2 TB on two separate HHD (so no external HDD) on a Alienware Dell laptop. (Ubuntu desktop 20.04LTS)
I made sure to allocate the partitions in the second hard drive as suggested and made a live USB with Ubuntu flashed on it via Balena Etcher.
Afterwards I boot from the USB and try to install Ubuntu. When I want to install it, I can't select my second hard drive. Ubuntu only shows the first hard drive which is used for windows and the USB drives and not the second which is reserved for Ubuntu.
How can I select the second hard drive so I can install Ubuntu on a separate drive than Windows?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvD98.png)

BIOS:
BIOS-versie/date    Alienware 1.4.0, 8/09/2021
SMBIOS-versie   3.3
Versie van ingesloten controller    255.255
BIOS-modus  UEFI

Thank you.

Comment: The above notwithstanding, did you at some point enabled software RAID, dynamic disks or some other Windows proprietary technology? Please [edit] you question accordingly, addressing the questions of both comments. You may include a screenshot of Windows' Drive manager.

Comment: I have the Alienware from Dell which has 4TB in total spread in 2 different disks. So there is no external disk present. I downloaded Ubuntu desktop and flashed it on a usb drive using balena etcher. Then I started up the boot from my USB stick to install ubuntu.

Comment: Please check UEFI ("BIOS"), drive mode setting. If it has something like "RAID" or "Intel RST", this modes aren't compatible. In that case you need to install AHCI support in Windows and then change to the same mode in UEFI. Also please remember to [edit] the question to add new information, not comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)